# Tkinter passing parameters

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 .py files in the same project, one called **namer** and the other called **GuiApp**

In namer is

```
def nameit(name):
    greetings = f'Hello {name}'
    print(greetings)
```

GuiApp holds:

```
from tkinter import *
from namer import nameit
from functools import partial

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.grid(row=4, column=3)
l1 = Label(window, text="Output", font=15)
l1.grid(row=6, column=0)
Btn = Button(window, text="Run X", fg="black", bg="gray", command=(nameit(txt.get())))
Btn.grid(row=4, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why when i type something into txt, it is not returned as part of the nameit function. Any ideas please as im new to Tkinter?

Comment: Change `command=(nameit(txt.get()))` to `command=lambda: nameit(txt.get())`

Comment: This code should not work due to indentation errors in the namer file. Please make sure your code is properly indented, or at least when you post it to StackOverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the command of a button has parenthesis, it makes it call the function. So, create an anonymous function like: `lambda: nameit(txt.get())`

**Solution:**

```
from tkinter import *
from namer import nameit
from functools import partial

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.grid(row=4, column=3)
l1 = Label(window, text="Output", font=15)
l1.grid(row=6, column=0)
Btn = Button(window, text="Run X", fg="black", bg="gray", command=lambda: nameit(txt.get()))
Btn.grid(row=4, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks a lot like my comment.

Comment: My comment is 4 min older than your answer and this isn't the first time this happens today. Either you coping my comments and posting them as your answers (for reputation?) or ...

Comment: I think it is the way you answered, it is not allowing me to mark yours as the answer Lizzard

Comment: @VadimNemkov Well for short fixes I just write comments but the problem is when people just copy/paste my answer and claim it as theirs. Most of the time they just do it for reputation.

Comment: @TheLizzard I wanted to make a full answer, not comment. I don't copy comment for reputation. I just wrote my answer.

Comment: @TheLizzard: you shouldn't be upset of someone creates an answer that looks like one of your comments. If you're not willing to make a proper answer, then there's nothing wrong with someone else doing so.

Comment: @BryanOakley That is just reputation hunting. I don't think it is ethical. Also if someone posts an answer that is similar to mine but in a short time span I would just forget about it. But this is the second time today that TkinterLover has turned my comment into their answer. This might just be a coincidence but I really doubt it.

Comment: I don't care about reputation, I care about quality answer!

Comment: But if don't want me "copying" can't you just make your own answer?

Also, you didn't specify why the OP should be using lambda's. I did.

Comment: @TkinterLover I always post what I think is the correct answer as a comment and if/when they confirm it has worked I ask them if they want me to write a proper answer. Please note that I only do this for simple solutions like this one. If I have to define a function or something that takes more work I write a proper answer.

Comment: @TheLizzard: _" I always post what I think is the correct answer as a comment and if/when they confirm it has worked"_ - that's not what comments were designed for. See  [When _shouldn't_ I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I'm guilty of this too, but it's a bad habit. When I do, and someone copies my comment to make an answer, I'm actually pleased rather than disappointed. I don't always have time to write a good answer, so I'm glad when someone can get inspiration and write a good answer so I don't have to.